# ssh: Identity not Loaded from Keychain at Startup

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh

I have configured a host in my `~/.ssh/config` like this

```
Host pptest
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test_2048_pp
UseKeychain yes
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

This key has a passphrase on it. As was my understanding, `UseKeychain` and `AddKeysToAgent` should automatically load the keys passphrase on reboot, however I have not found this to be the case. To get for instance a `git-fetch` (or any remote action involving ssh) working, I still need to run an

```
ssh-add
```

beforehand.

Why is this happening?

My system is `10.15.5 (19F96)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared once I manually added the key in the shell using

```
ssh-add -K <path/to/key>
```

Now the key is also loaded at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `ssh-copy-id` of your public key to your host? If not the

```
UseKeychain yes
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

is meaningless, since the host has no way of verifying who you are, and will ask for the password or passphrase.
Take a look at [Taming the terminal part 30/37](https://www.bartbusschots.ie/s/2015/03/29/taming-the-terminal-part-30-of-n-sshing-more-securely/) for an explanation.
Also `man ssh-copy-id` should give you more info.

Comment: Of course, otherwise a connection would not even be possible, even if I entered my private key passphrase.